# Syncing Threads in Boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I am trying to create an application which create one main thread and 10 slave threads. I want to run the slave threads once after the main thread is run. So for each main thread execution, each slave thread is going to execute once. I tried to handle this with two different `conditional variables`. So, one is used for slave threads so they can wait until the main thread notify them and another `conditional variable` for the main thread which is signaled after each child finish its task, so the main thread can check if all the slave threads are done or not. The code is as follows:

```
// STD 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


// BOOST
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

std::vector<boost::thread*> threads;

std::vector<boost::mutex*> data_ready_mutex;
std::vector<boost::condition_variable*> cond;
std::vector<bool> data_ready;
std::vector<int> num_run;

boost::mutex check_finish_mutex;
std::vector<bool> finished;

boost::atomic<int> data;
boost::atomic<int> next_thread_id;

boost::mutex finished_task_mutex;
boost::condition_variable finished_task_cond;
bool finished_task = false;

void signal_finished(const int& id)
{
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(finished_task_mutex);
    finished[id] = true;
    finished_task = true;
  }
  finished_task_cond.notify_all();
}

void signal_slave(const int& id)
{
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(*data_ready_mutex[id]);

    data_ready[id] = true;
  }
  cond[id]->notify_all();
}

void slave_therad()
{
  int id = next_thread_id++;

  std::cout << "( " << id << " ) slave_thread created\n";
  while (true)
  {
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(*data_ready_mutex[id]);
    while (!data_ready[id])
    {
      cond[id]->wait(lock);
    }

    finished[id] = false;

    data_ready[id] = false;

    data++;

    num_run[id]++;

    signal_finished(id);
  }
}

void main()
{
  size_t nThreads = 10;

  data_ready_mutex.resize(nThreads);
  cond.resize(nThreads);
  data_ready.resize(nThreads);
  finished.resize(nThreads);
  num_run.resize(nThreads, 0);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    data_ready_mutex[i] = new boost::mutex();
    cond[i] = new boost::condition_variable();
    data_ready[i] = false;
    finished[i] = false;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    threads.push_back(new boost::thread(slave_therad));
  }

  while (true)
  {
    clock_t start_time = clock();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++)
      signal_slave(static_cast<int>(i));

    while (true)
    {
      boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(finished_task_mutex);
      while (!finished_task)
      {
        finished_task_cond.wait(lock);
      }
      finished_task = false;

      size_t i = 0;
      for (; i < finished.size(); i++)
      {
        if (!finished[i]) break;
      }
      if (i == finished.size()) break;
    }

    clock_t end_time = clock();

    std::cout << "Elapsed Time = " << static_cast<float>(end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++)
      finished[i] = false;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    threads[i]->join();
  }
}
```

The problem is that somewhere the code stops and it stuck in deadlock.

Also, I tried to change the way to implement. So, I used an `atomic<int>` which counts the number of threads which has finished their task and in the main thread I check if the number of threads is equal to number of threads which has updated themselves but this method also stuck somewhere and goes into deadlock. 
The code can be found here:

```
// STD 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


// BOOST
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

std::vector<boost::thread*> threads;                //!< Slave Threads array

std::vector<boost::mutex*>  data_ready_mutex;       //!< Mutex to guard the data_ready 
std::vector<bool>           data_ready;             //!< Shows if the data is ready for the slave thread or not.
std::vector<boost::condition_variable*> cond;       //!< conditional variable to wait on data being ready for the slave thread.

std::vector<int> num_run;                           //!< Stores the number of times each slave thread is run.

boost::atomic<int> data;                            //!< Stores the data processed by each slave thread
boost::atomic<int> next_thread_id;                  //!< id for the next thread (used for giving an id from 0,..., nThreads-1

boost::atomic<int> num_threads_done;                //!< Stores the number of slave threads which has finished their task

//! Signals a slave thread to start its task
void signal_slave(const int& id)
{
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(*data_ready_mutex[id]);
    data_ready[id] = true;
  }
  cond[id]->notify_all();
}

//! Slave thread function
void slave_therad()
{
  // assign an id to the current slave_thread
  int id = next_thread_id++;

  std::cout << "( " << id << " ) slave_thread created\n";
  while (true)
  {
    // wait for a signal from the main thread
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(*data_ready_mutex[id]);
    while (!data_ready[id])
    {
      cond[id]->wait(lock);
    }

    // make the data not ready, so the loop is not going to run without the main thread signal after the thread is done.
    data_ready[id] = false;

    // TASK for SLAVE THREAD
    data++;

    // Increase the number of times the thread is run
    num_run[id]++;

    // Increase the number of threads which has finished their tasks.
    num_threads_done++;

  }
}

void main()
{
  size_t nThreads = 10;

  // creating the data ready mutexes, conditional variables, data_ready variable (bools), num_runs array.
  data_ready_mutex.resize(nThreads);
  cond.resize(nThreads);
  data_ready.resize(nThreads);
  num_run.resize(nThreads, 0);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    data_ready_mutex[i] = new boost::mutex();
    cond[i] = new boost::condition_variable();
    data_ready[i] = false;
  }

  // Creating the slave threads
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    threads.push_back(new boost::thread(slave_therad));
  }

  // Main Thread Body
  while (true)
  {
    clock_t start_time = clock();

    // Reset the number of threads which are done.
    num_threads_done = 0;

    // Signals the slave threads to start doing their task.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++)
      signal_slave(static_cast<int>(i));

    // Wait until all the slave threads are done.
    while (true)
      if (num_threads_done == threads.size()) break;

    clock_t end_time = clock();

    std::cout << "Elapsed Time = " << static_cast<float>(end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    threads[i]->join();
  }

}
```

Even, I tried to fix the issue with barriers but it did not fix my problem. the code is as follows:

```
// STD 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


// BOOST
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

boost::barrier* barrier;                            //!< barrier to make sure all the slave threads are done their tasks.

std::vector<boost::thread*> threads;

std::vector<boost::mutex*>  data_ready_mutex;       //!< Mutex to guard the data_ready 
std::vector<bool>           data_ready;             //!< Shows if the data is ready for the slave thread or not.
std::vector<boost::condition_variable*> cond;       //!< conditional variable to wait on data being ready for the slave thread.

std::vector<int> num_run;                           //!< Stores the number of times each slave thread is run.

boost::atomic<int> data;                            //!< Stores the data processed by each slave thread
boost::atomic<int> next_thread_id;                  //!< id for the next thread (used for giving an id from 0,..., nThreads-1

boost::atomic<int> num_threads_done;                //!< Stores the number of slave threads which has finished their task

std::vector<bool> finished;                         //!< Array which stores if all the slave threads are done or not.
boost::mutex finished_task_mutex;                   //!< mutex to guard the finished_task variable
boost::condition_variable finished_task_cond;       //!< Conditional variable to wait for all the threads to finish they tasks.
boost::atomic<bool> finished_task(false);           //!< Variable which stores if the task of slave_threads are finished or not.

void signal_finished(const int& id)
{
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(finished_task_mutex);
    finished[id] = true;
    finished_task = true;
  }
  finished_task_cond.notify_all();
}

void signal_slave(const int& id)
{
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(*data_ready_mutex[id]);

    data_ready[id] = true;
  }
  cond[id]->notify_all();
}

void slave_therad()
{
  int id = next_thread_id++;

  std::cout << "( " << id << " ) slave_thread created\n";
  while (true)
  {
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(*data_ready_mutex[id]);
    while (!data_ready[id])
    {
      cond[id]->wait(lock);
    }

    finished[id] = false;

    data_ready[id] = false;

    data++;

    num_run[id]++;

    barrier->wait();

    signal_finished(id);
  }
}

void main()
{
  size_t nThreads = 10;

  data_ready_mutex.resize(nThreads);
  cond.resize(nThreads);
  data_ready.resize(nThreads);
  finished.resize(nThreads);
  num_run.resize(nThreads, 0);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    data_ready_mutex[i] = new boost::mutex();
    cond[i] = new boost::condition_variable();
    data_ready[i] = false;
    finished[i] = false;
  }

  barrier = new boost::barrier(nThreads);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    threads.push_back(new boost::thread(slave_therad));
  }

  while (true)
  {
    clock_t start_time = clock();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++)
      signal_slave(static_cast<int>(i));

    while (true)
    {
      boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(finished_task_mutex);
      while (!finished_task)
      {
        finished_task_cond.wait(lock);
      }
      finished_task = false;
      break;
    }

    clock_t end_time = clock();

    std::cout << "Elapsed Time = " << static_cast<float>(end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++)
      finished[i] = false;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    threads[i]->join();
  }
}
```

[UPDATED]
So, I simply used the `mutex`, `conditional variables` and `data_ready` in a struct as follows and now the code is working. I think there was a bug with using `pointer to mutex` and so on. the code is as follows:

```
//#define SYNC_WITH_BARRIER
#define SYNC_WITH_ATOMICS

// STD 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


// BOOST
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

std::vector<boost::thread*> threads;

boost::atomic<int> next_thread_id(0);

boost::mutex finished_task_mutex;
boost::condition_variable finished_task_cond;
bool finished_task = false;

boost::atomic<int> num_finished_tasks(0);

struct Work
{
  Work(boost::barrier& _barrier) : b(&_barrier)
  {

  }

  boost::barrier*           b;
  boost::mutex              data_ready_mutex;
  boost::condition_variable data_ready_cond;
  bool                      data_ready;
  int                       num_run;
  boost::atomic<int>        data;
  bool                      finished;

  void signal_slave()
  {
    {
      boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(data_ready_mutex);
      data_ready = true;
      data_ready_cond.notify_all();
    }    
  }

  void slave_therad()
  {
    int id = next_thread_id++;

    std::cout << "( " << id << " ) slave_thread created\n";
    while (true)
    {
      boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(data_ready_mutex);
      while (!data_ready)
      {
        data_ready_cond.wait(lock);
      }

      finished = false;

      data_ready = false;

      data++;

      num_run++;

#ifdef SYNC_WITH_BARRIER
      b->count_down_and_wait();
#else 
#ifdef SYNC_WITH_ATOMICS
      num_finished_tasks++;
#endif
#endif
    }
  }

};

#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/chrono_io.hpp>

using hrc = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

void main()
{
  size_t nThreads = 10;

  boost::thread_group tg;
  boost::ptr_vector<Work> work_items;
  work_items.reserve(nThreads);

  boost::barrier finish(nThreads + 1); // one for the main thread

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    work_items.push_back(new Work(finish));
    tg.create_thread(boost::bind(&Work::slave_therad, boost::ref(work_items.back()))); 
  }

  while (true)
  {
    auto start_time = hrc::now();

    num_finished_tasks = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < work_items.size(); i++)
      work_items[i].signal_slave();

#ifdef SYNC_WITH_BARRIER
    finish.count_down_and_wait();
#else
#ifdef SYNC_WITH_ATOMICS
    while (true) if (num_finished_tasks == work_items.size()) break;
#endif
#endif

    clock_t end_time = clock();

    std::cout << "Elapsed Time = " << hrc::now() - start_time << std::endl;

  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
  {
    threads[i]->join();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Niall I tried to create threads after setting up the cond variables etc. but it still stuck in deadlock

Comment: also, in signal_slave(),  cond[id]->notify_all() must be done when mutex is locked

Comment: why allocate threads, mutexes, cond variables dynamically? why just don't  resize vector to required size? also why keep them separate in 3 vectors? why just don't make one struct that keeps all stuff for thread - thread, muext, condition, data flag and then vector of such structs? to me this would be more compact and clear. don't mind, just a recommendation.

Comment: @ivan.ukr I also tried that but it didn't work. Furthermore, if you have a look on Boost's conditional variable documentation [http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref], the `notify_*` is done when the mutex is not locked.

Comment: @ivan.ukr I cannot make a vector of `boost::mutex` because of 

`Error 1 error C2280: 'boost::mutex::mutex(const boost::mutex &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function` error.

Comment: Why don't you use C++ threads, obviously you have support for C++11, don't you? BTW: All the globals without any reasonable documentation don't make the code more easy to understand and get right....

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have but what is the difference. They are almost the same.

Comment: You can `std::move()` a `std::thread` into a container, avoiding the dynamic allocation, which to me is reason enough already.

Comment: Another question, you create a thread and then immediately wait for it to finish, is that necessary to demonstrate the issue? BTW: whenever you have vectors where elements with the same index correspond to each other, consider using a single vector with a structure instead.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt which thread do you mean? The `slave_thread` is waiting for signal from the `main_thread` and the `main_thread` is waiting for `slave_thread`s to finish.

Comment: Ulrich is right, try to place mThread.join(); to the end of main()

Comment: That's not what I meant, @Ivan. The useless thread `mThread` inside `main()` could be replaced with a simple call to the thread's function. BTW: `main()` already runs in a thread (you *alway* have *at* *least* one thread!), so the name is slightly misleading.

Comment: @ivan.ukr I tried to use conditional variables so the `slave_thread`s signal the `main_thread` because I wanted to get rid of ` while (true) if (num_threads_done == threads.size()) break`

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes. You are right  but still it is not fixing the issue.

Comment: also things like     while (true)
        if (num_threads_done == threads.size()) break; are better done with another condition variable because in real scenarios lead to unnecessary cpu waste

Comment: Or a barrier/semaphore

Comment: did you try to run the program under debugger and break it and see where it is stuck?

Comment: @ivan.ukr yes. It stuck in the ` while (true)
      if (num_threads_done == threads.size()) break;` because the `num_threads_done =11`. It seems one of threads are executed 2 times.

Comment: ok agree with @UlrichEckhardt - additional "main" thread can be avoided just by calling its routine from main()

Comment: @sehe What do you mean?

Comment: instead of boost::thread mThread(main_thread);

  mThread.join(); you just call main_thread()

Comment: @sehe even with barrier, it stuck in deadlock.

Comment: I've done some tests and it seems that sometimes a thread does an additional round. My humble guess there is that the compiler or CPU reorders a few things, concerning the access to the atomics. After all, while the operations on the atomics are guaranteed to be atomic, they can be reordered (AFAIK) and the memory fence guarantee of a mutex doesn't apply here. BTW: You also shouldn't need `notify_all()`, since at most one thread is waiting on each of the condition variables.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am using Visual Studio 2013. I tried to compile with disabling all the optimizations but it still has the same problem.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt So, I simply replace my pointer mutexs, cond_vars, and so on with struct of work and now, the code is working with `barrier` and also with `atomic_finished_tasks` counter which was not working before. I think there was a bug with pointer to mutex or something like that. You can see the code in last part of the question (marked with [Updated]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @sehe even with barrier, it stuck in deadlock. –  mmostajab [5 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241999/syncing-threads-in-boost?noredirect=1#comment50484282_31241999)

Since youdon't show anything about what you're doing there, let me give you a startup boost by incorporating a large chunk of all the suggestions you received:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9881908c189f82e8)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace /*static*/ {
    boost::atomic<int> data;
    boost::atomic<int> num_threads_done;

    struct Work {
        void signal_slave()
        {
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(data_ready_mutex);
            data_ready = true;
            cond.notify_all();
        }

        void slave_thread()
        {
            static boost::atomic_int _id_gen(0);
            id = _id_gen++;

            std::cout << "(" << id << ") slave_thread created\n";
            while (true) {

                boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(data_ready_mutex);
                cond.wait(lock, [&]{ return data_ready; });

                data_ready = false;

                data++;

                num_run++;

                num_threads_done++;
            }
        }

      private:
        int id          = 0;
        bool data_ready = false;
        int  num_run    = 0;

        boost::mutex data_ready_mutex;
        boost::condition_variable cond;

    };

}

#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/chrono_io.hpp>

using hrc = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group tg;

    size_t nThreads = 10;

    std::vector<Work> works(nThreads);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        tg.create_thread(boost::bind(&Work::slave_thread, boost::ref(works[i])));
    }

    while (true) {
        auto start_time = hrc::now();

        for (auto& w : works)
            w.signal_slave();

        std::cout << "Elapsed Time = " << (hrc::now()-start_time) << std::endl;
    }

    tg.join_all();
}
```

Bear in mind, I don't know what you're trying to achieve here. Adding a barrier I had this in mind: [how to use boost barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407577/how-to-use-boost-barrier)

Comment: This does something completely different, because the original main loop always issued a task to all workers and then *waited* for them to finish before dealing the next round.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes. You are right but I added the conditional variable to the main thread to wait for the slave threads and it works without any problems.

Comment: Now, my question is what is the difference between my code and yours? (Other than being clear)? They are doing the same thing but mine is not working.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what "I added the condition variable" means in code. A condition variable always means an associated mutex and thus it also implies a memory barrier. Concerning the relevance of a barrier, see my comment on reordering of atomic operations above.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I agree. I posted this in the first place because we need to look at code: _"Since you don't show anything about what you're doing there ..."_. I even said I didn't understand what the OP was trying to achieve. I changed many things (using predicate condition wait, signalling under lock, etc. I don't see how `num_threads_done++` is adding info beyond `data++` etc)

Comment: @sehe, thanks for your effort! Big part of my confusion comes from the fact that your attempt to extract a clean example was (IMHO blindly) accepted as solution. Since your code works significantly different though, I raised that issue.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt again, [completely agreed](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24283645#24283645)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I changed the answer so it exactly do what I wanted to achieve with the above code and I posted it in a separate answer. can you please have a look on it?

Comment: In recation to the OP's self-answer update: _In that case, still avoid manual memory management, shared globals, magic flags (I think the finish flag was broken): **[cleaned up](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b89bd1fbccab287)**._

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change the @sehe answer, so it solve exactly the problem which I am looking for and I achieved this code:

```
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace /*static*/ {
  boost::atomic<int> data;

  boost::barrier*           slave_thread_finished_barrier;
  boost::mutex              slave_thread_finished_mutex; 
  boost::condition_variable slave_thread_finished_cond;
  bool                      slave_thread_finished = false;

  struct Work {
    void signal_slave()
    {
      boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(data_ready_mutex);
      data_ready = true;
      cond.notify_all();
    }

    void slave_thread()
    {
      static boost::atomic_int _id_gen(0);
      id = _id_gen++;

      std::cout << "(" << id << ") slave_thread created\n";
      while (true) {

        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(data_ready_mutex);
        cond.wait(lock, [&]{ return data_ready; });

        data_ready = false;

        data++;

        num_run++;

        slave_thread_finished_barrier->wait();

        // signaling the main thread that the slave threads are done.
        if (id == 0)
        {
          boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(slave_thread_finished_mutex);
          slave_thread_finished = true;
          slave_thread_finished_cond.notify_one();
        }

      }
    }

  private:
    int id = 0;
    bool data_ready = false;
    int  num_run = 0;

    boost::mutex data_ready_mutex;
    boost::condition_variable cond;

  };

}

#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/chrono_io.hpp>

using hrc = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

int main()
{
  boost::thread_group tg;

  size_t nThreads = 10;

  slave_thread_finished_barrier = new boost::barrier(nThreads);
  std::vector<Work> works(nThreads);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
    tg.create_thread(boost::bind(&Work::slave_thread, boost::ref(works[i])));
  }

  while (true) {
    auto start_time = hrc::now();

    for (auto& w : works)
      w.signal_slave();

    // Wait for slave threads to finish.
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(slave_thread_finished_mutex);
    slave_thread_finished_cond.wait(lock, [&]{ return slave_thread_finished; });
    slave_thread_finished = false;

    std::cout << "Elapsed Time = " << (hrc::now() - start_time) << std::endl;
  }

  tg.join_all();
}
```

Comment: In that case, still avoid manual memory management, shared globals, magic flags (I think the finish flag was broken): ***[cleaned up](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b89bd1fbccab287)***