# How do I efficiently wait for all threads to complete task before starting the next one?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've been trying to build an Entity Component System in C++, and I've got it working, but the code that I've written to handle the waiting between phases is very inefficient.

I've got two phases currently. The first one is Ticking, where all of the threads go through all of the systems and tick the ones that are tickable. The second stage is the Resolution stage, where each thread takes a number of systems and add and remove components from them.

Anyways, after each phase I have each thread atomically increment a variable and busy wait until all of the threads have incremented that variable. Once both stages are complete, I follow the same pattern in reverse (decrement each and wait till zero), and signal the main thread that the threads are done with the current tick.

Is there a better way to do this? Currently this causes a slowdown of about 17 ms with 8 threads, and I'd like to make it faster if possible.

Below is my code. Please excuse the poor code quality; I've been poking and prodding at it and haven't cleaned it up (especially the memory_orders).

```
    void Engine::threadRun(uint64_t a_ThreadID)
    {
    m_Mutex.lock();
    std::cerr << "Thread #" << a_ThreadID << " starting." << std::endl;
    m_Mutex.unlock();

    while (m_State.load(std::memory_order_acq_rel) > STOPPED)
    {
        if (m_State.load(std::memory_order_acq_rel) == RUNNING)
        {
            for (auto itr = m_Systems->begin(); itr != m_Systems->end(); ++itr)
            {
                auto a_system = itr->second;
                if(a_system->isTickable())
                {
                    a_system->tick(m_ThreadCount, a_ThreadID, m_DT.load(std::memory_order_release));
                }
            }

            // Wait until all threads are done to move onto the resolution phase
            m_Mutex.lock();
            m_TickStageCompleted.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
            m_Mutex.unlock();
            while(m_TickStageCompleted.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != m_ThreadCount);

            size_t count = m_Systems->size() / m_ThreadCount + 1; // How many per thread
            auto start_idx = count * a_ThreadID;
            if (start_idx < m_Systems->size())
            {
                // There's got to be a better way to start at a specific index in a map
                // Maybe switch to two vectors with one storing the name and the other the system
                auto index = m_Systems->begin();
                std::advance(index, (start_idx));
                auto end = index;

                while(end != m_Systems->end() && count)
                {
                    ++end;
                    --count;
                }

                for (; index != end && index != m_Systems->end(); ++index)
                {
                    index->second->resolve();
                }
            }
            /**
             * This section is super inefficient. I need to find a better way of doing this
             **/
            // Wait until resolutions are complete to continue
            m_Mutex.lock();
            m_ResolutionStageCompleted.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
            m_Mutex.unlock();
            while(m_ResolutionStageCompleted.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != m_ThreadCount);

            // Signal the main thread that this run completed successfully
            m_State.store(PAUSED, std::memory_order_release);

            // Reset everything
            m_Mutex.lock();
            m_TickStageCompleted.fetch_sub(1);
            m_Mutex.unlock();
            while(m_TickStageCompleted.load(std::memory_order_release) != 0);

            m_Mutex.lock();
            m_ResolutionStageCompleted.fetch_sub(1);
            m_Mutex.unlock();
            while(m_ResolutionStageCompleted.load(std::memory_order_release) != 0);
        }
    }
    m_Mutex.lock();
    std::cerr << "Thread #" << a_ThreadID << " ending." << std::endl;
    m_Mutex.unlock();
}
```

Comment: First job is to replace busy waits with condition variables

Comment: You could maybe use a *boost* barrier wait... https://stackoverflow.com/a/11408125/2836621

Comment: So you essentially made a cyclic barrier?

Which part takes 17-18ms? That sounds to me like a very long time. 

How many cores are you running on?

My first advice would be that if you don't know which `memory_order` to use, use `seq_cst`. (But you have to use it for all, no mixing.)

I'm curious to know why you lock the atomic before an increment. This is not necessary, since you're just doing 1 operation on an `std::atomic`. It could be the source of your poor performance.

Comment: This is a port of a c version that I made. I started using the mutex when the atomic wasn't updating as expected no matter what memory_order I used (I was using release to store and acquire to read initiall IIRC), and I can definitely believe that it is causing the slowdown. It's been so long since I learned about memory order I don't really remember which is which.
I'm running on 4 cores.
The lock/unlock sections take the longest.